# Why wouldn't Visual Studio let me set form size?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, size

Given: screen resolution will be 1920 x 1080.

I am trying to set windows form to 1920 x 1080, however it won't let me, the form size automatically resets to 1378 x 780 whenever I try to set a larger size.

(My laptop is 1366 x 768, does that have anything to do with it?)

I googled, but the results were about resizing forms. I am not trying to resize the forms dynamically or otherwise, I am trying to set an unchangeable size to it.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?
Or if you can suggest a better way than setting a fixed size to the forms?

Comment: Have you set the MaximumSize and MinimumSize properties?

Comment: You cannot make a window larger than your screen.

Comment: @adv12 yeah~ MaximumSize is set to 1920 1080, MinimumSize is the largest possible (1364, 726).

Comment: @HansPassant so.... I must connect to a larger screen then? o.0 Sounds weird, I'll give that a try though...

Comment: Well, not exactly weird, the user can't ever get to the part of the window that is off the screen.  This is going to happen on the user's machine as well, you cannot dictate what size screen he'll use.  So you'd better make it work on your laptop.  Focus on making the window easily resizable.  When that works well enough then you just don't care about the screen size.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I'll be giving the users the screens that I choose, so I guess temporarily, it will be alright to fix a size. BUT, I'll take the helpful advice! Always smart to make the program versatile, hehe :D:D Thank you! I'm off to read about resizing :D